# Override PHP OpenSSL config

Tags: php-fpm, openssl

Is it possible to tell php to read a specific openssl.cnf file instead of default one?

```
# php --info | grep "Openssl"
Openssl default config => /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf
```

Using PHP-FPM so a per-pool option would be fine using `php_admin_value[]`

Or having a per user (linux) config file by placing a config file in their home, if possible?

Tried as ENV variables as per https://www.php.net/manual/en/openssl.installation.php but only global (/usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf) edit works.

[image]

Comment: Did you try [what is documented](https://www.php.net/manual/en/openssl.installation.php)?

Comment: Yes I've tried `env[OPENSSL_CONF] = /my/location/openssl.cnf` in my config pool, restarted PHP, but doesn't seem to be valid. But if I edit the main `/usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf` PHP reads it correctly (same configuration).

Comment: I've also tried all the variations I know of setting environment variables at runtime and am unable to override `OPENSSL_CONF` such that it is obeyed when making a curl request.

Answer (score 2):

*EDIT: I realize that this might not really answer the whole question, as this solution is a global workaround and not per fpm-pool.*

*In my scenario I just wanted PHP to use a different `openssl.cnf` as it required some typical changes not suitable for the OS.*

---

PHP and OpenSSL are a real pain.
You have to pass the environment variable to the fpm-php executable to get this working, and that is easier said than done...

As POC: this will work: `OPENSSL_CONF=/my/location/openssl.cnf /usr/sbin/php-fpm8.1`

Problem is to get this working with systemV or systemD.
systemV will look for `/etc/default/$NAME` (in this example `/etc/default/php-fpm8.1`) if the file does not exist, you can create it and add:

```bash
OPENSSL_CONF=/my/location/openssl.cnf
```

in theory `/etc/init.d/php8.1-fpm restart` should now pass the environment variable.

on Debian however, this didn't work. I had the make changes tot systemD too. (creating an override).

`sudo systemctl edit php8.1-fpm` and change the whole content to the following:

```bash
[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/php-fpm8.1
```

This will create an override file, `sudo systemctl restart php8.1-fpm` will now pick-up the system environment variable and shows the new `Openssl default config`.

Hope this helps, and the info is helpful for other people too.

I have not tested this on RHEL based linux, but I expect the systemD override will just do the trick.

**please NOTE:** PHP (cli) is unaffected, in order to make this work you should just set the `OPENSSL_CONF` variable before executing.

```bash
OPENSSL_CONF=/my/location/openssl.cnf php8.1 -i | grep Openssl
Openssl default config => /my/location/openssl.cnf
```